# What means "coping resources"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, expressions

"With ISTPs, had the lowest mean level of coping resources; ranked 16th out of 16 types on total resources." (src: http://www.discoveryourpersonality.com/intp.html)

I would like to know what coping resources means in this sentence.

Comment: Without buying into the personality theories expressed there, "coping resources" would refer to character traits which allow one to adapt to adverse or difficult circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Coping** generally means to **get by**, to fight your battles without giving up.
In this case, **coping resources** would mean the ability that someone has to fight through the difficulties he encounters without minding too much and while keeping his calm.